# AngularJS kickstart with Yeoman - bower_components missing

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am currently learning AngularJS and the Test Driven Development concept so I was watching the [introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDB-jm8MWro) and now where I want to start the server via "grunt server" it throws an error with something like "bower_components directory not found". I definately installed Bower but the error still occurs.

I'm using Windows 7, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to install the Bower components. Run the following in your terminal:

```
bower install
```